# Controller of Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

*Hi All,*

I have an edit button

`<span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="edit" action="edit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" /></span>`

But when click on it the adderess on the browser was not http:\...\edit,
 it was http:\...\index. Why?

I tried to delete or rename the name of Edit in controller, it still not influence. Why?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you show us your entire form, the link looks OK, maybe it's your definition of the `<g:form/>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying controller's name with `g:form` like

```
<g:form controller="CONTROLLER_NAME">
```